# WiFi Password with Command Prompt windows 8.1

Tags: security, cmd, passwords, wifi, computer-science

I used this command to get connected WiFi password:

```
netsh wlan show profile name="my profile name" key=clear
```

but it doesn't show security key, it says:

```
key content = absent
```

Is there still any way to get it? why is it absent?

Comment: Run command prompt as administrator and try again

Answer (score 1):

From Help

```
netsh wlan show profile /?
```

> If key is set to "clear" and the caller is local administrator,
>   the key will be shown in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this batch file to get all of the ssid's and passwords from your system. Copy and paste the code below into notepad and save it as `get_ssid_pwd.cmd` and then open `cmd` as administrator, `cd` to the directory where you save the file and run it as `get_ssid_pwd.cmd`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile ^|find /i "All User Profile"') do (
    set "ssid=%%~a"
    call :getpwd %%ssid:~1%%
)
:getpwd
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="%*" key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"') do echo ssid: %* pass: %%i
```