# How can you automatically find out the WiFi passwords on Windows using Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am thanks to [this (german) site](https://itler.net/wlan-passwort-anzeigen-ueber-eingabeaufforderung-cmd/) aware of the batch command

```
netsh wlan show profile
```

to show the names of all safed WiFi networks like this:

```
...
Benutzerprofile
---------------
    Profil fr alle Benutzer : <wifi network name 1>
    Profil fr alle Benutzer : <wifi network name 2>
...
```

After that, one can use

```
netsh wlan show profile <Name> key=clear
```

where `<Name>` stands for the name of the respective network gained e.g. above.

Is it possible to automatically combine the two?

Comment: Give a try for this batch tested on french machines [Wifi Passwords Recovery.bat](https://pastebin.com/Ntc8SZLU)

Answer (score 2):

This is one I did a [while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099326/wifi-password-with-command-prompt-windows-8-1/59113556#59113556) and does not need `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile ^|findstr ":"') do (
    set "ssid=%%~a"
    call :getpwd "%%ssid:~1%%"
)
:getpwd
set "ssid=%*"
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="%ssid:"=%" key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"') do echo ssid: %ssid% pass: %%i
```

Comment: @jeb Thanks for the edit, my damn keyboard always capitalises stand alone I :)

Comment: Works for all my Wifi's with some strange names, but it's not language independent. The first `FIND` can be changed to `findstr ":"`, that should work with the most languages. Only the second one seems to be a bit tricky

Comment: @jeb yeah true, let me think of some language independent ways

Comment: Your `call :getpwd %%ssid:~1%%` seems to be risky for content like `&|<>` and so on. And it seems to be [allowed in SSID names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450037/463115)! Luckily, I don't have such names, until now

Comment: @jeb made the change for the possible special characters. Will spend some time later to make this language independent.

Answer (score 0):

For the for a bit below and the `:Trim` part ([thanks to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch/26079981#26079981) [or 2](https://www.borncity.com/blog/2016/04/26/windows-10-gespeicherte-wlan-kennwrter-auslesen/)), delayed expansion is needed to make the variables within this batch file be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time. Usage: variables delimited by exclamation marks (!) are evaluated on execution. 
This will ensure the correct behavior in this case.

`echo|set /p="test text"` gives a text without newline ([thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7105690/4575793)).

`for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in (SavedNetworks.temp) do (...)` gives you the second token each line, seperated by a `:` ([source](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/kann-mir-jemand-sagen-wie-ich-den-wert-001-aus-der-txt-datei-werte-auslese-dessen-einzige-zeile---erzeugte-antworten--------------------001-ist-via-batch)).

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo|set /p="Lese die existierenden Netzwerke ein:"
netsh wlan show profile > SavedNetworks.temp
@echo|set /p="Verarbeite die eingelesenen Netzwerke (1):"
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in (SavedNetworks.temp) do (
call :Trim Actual %%i
netsh wlan show profile "!Actual!" key=clear >> SavedNetworks2.temp 
) 
@echo on
move SavedNetworks2.temp SavedNetworks.temp 
@echo|set /p="Verarbeite die eingelesenen Netzwerke (2):"
findstr "SSID-Name Sicherheitsschlssel Schlsselinhalt" SavedNetworks.temp >> SavedNetworks.txt
::notepad SavedNetworks.temp 
del SavedNetworks.temp 
notepad SavedNetworks.txt
::pause
exit /b

:Trim
::Line below already at the top.
::SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Params=%*
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("!Params!") do EndLocal & set %1=%%b
exit /b
```

Unfortunately, this script does not work for all languages, namely here: `findstr "SSID-Name Sicherheitsschlssel Schlsselinhalt" SavedNetworks.temp >> SavedNetworks.txt` (found it [here](https://www.windowspro.de/wolfgang-sommergut/findstr-das-grep-fuer-windows), command and output are the german version). To find the right words for your language, uncomment `::notepad SavedNetworks.temp` and put a `::` in front of the next line. Run it and replace `"SSID-Name Sicherheitsschlssel Schlsselinhalt"` fittingly.

Comment: It misses all SSID's with an exclamation mark! That's all `FRITZ!Box ...` WiFi's

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I wrote it:

#### File: ShowWiFi.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile') do (
    set wifi_pwd=
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=: usebackq" %%F IN (`netsh wlan show profile %%a key^=clear ^| find "Key Content"`) do (
        set wifi_pwd=%%F
    )
    echo %%a : !wifi_pwd!
)
```

## Example Output

```
C:\>ShowWiFi
 Fiber5G :  SomePassword
 Courtyard_GUEST :
 redroof :
 Axon :  Password2
 Taco Bell WiFi :
 abelenkWiFi :  January
 SPS Internal :
C:\>
```

This didn't show all passwords for some reason, but did show many of them.

Comment: This fails for SSID's with spaces, like your own example shows for `Taco Bell WiFi`. You have to use `nestsh wlan show profile name="%%a" key=clear`. It still fails for SSID's with exclamation marks